# Batch file to aid repetitive task

Tags: batch-file

Hi there pretty new here and trying to come up with a quick where to automate a task i have...

I have a folder containing thousands of similar .txt files

In each of these text files there is a set format

Example

```
name      get_"random text"     name2   "random text2"
```

This line is repeated many times with random text changing on each line (sometimes there are blank spaces between each line and random symbols)

I need to get the information into this format and print it at the end of the .txt file it is looking at

```
"random text" :: "random text 2" := "random text 2" :: "random text 3"
```

`random text 3` Is the same for all lines but set at start by user

is it possible to write a batch file to do this repetitive task?

Comment: Given this statement, 'sometimes there are blank spaces between each line and random symbols', and your use of 'random', either provide a more expansive and representative example text file content, or expect your question to be closed.

Comment: Expanding on Compo's comment, do `name` and `name1` always represent those _exact_ characters, or could a line in question be `Matilda   get_"sdsddsd"    Alfred "sdasdsad"`? If the latter, is the presence of `get_` a sufficient criterion to distinguish the lines you want to extract data from?

Comment: Two further questions: (1) are the double-quotes (`"`) actually in the file, or are you just using them to highlight the bits you want? (2) Can the random text contain spaces and/or double-quotes?

Comment: thanks for responding so fast! in response to Tripehound - name and name1 are fixed  and get_ would be sufficient to distinguish the lines of text i would like to extract. Quotations were used to highlight the bits of text i want so they would not be in the text.

Comment: I really would like to see a "real-life" example of the text file (especially: are those all spaces or are there TABs too (and where)) and the desired output. There is too much open for guessing to come up with a useful solution.